# cannot add AxMODI.AxMiDocView in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, ocr

I am now trying to develop OCR application using MODI. so i want to use together with AxMODI.AxMiDocView controller. how should I do ? I added MODI 12.0 as reference. and I also chose "Microsoft Office Document Imaging Viewer Control 12.0" in toolbox but I cannot see the viewer. Although I create in code as the following,

```
AxMODI.AxMiDocView MiDoc1=new AxMODI.AxMiDocView();
```

it is still unrecognized for the viewer.

Comment: FYI, the language is "C#", not "C#.NET"

Comment: I am also facing this problem. "The following controls were successfully added to the toolbox but are not enabled in the active designer: Microsoft Office Document Imaging Viewer Control 11.0"